# Which of vsize, size and rss should be used in memory leak detection?

Tags: c, memory, rss, size

Which of the three values, *vsize*, *size* and *rss* from `ps` output is suitable for use in quick memory leak detection? For my purpose, if a process has been running for few days and its memory has kept increasing then that is a good enough indicator that it is leaking memory. I understand that a tool like valgrind should ultimately be used but its use is intrusive and so not always desirable.

For my understanding, I wrote a simple piece of C code that basically allocates 1 MiB of memory, frees it and then allocates 1 MiB again. It also sleeps before every step for 10 seconds giving me time to see output from `ps -p <pid> -ovsize=,size=,rss=`. Here it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define info(args...) printf(args)

char* bytes(char* str, uint32_t size, uint32_t n)
{
    char* unit = "B";

    if (n > 1000) {
        n /= 1000;
        unit = "KB";
    }
    if (n > 1000) {
        n /= 1000;
        unit = "MB";
    }

    snprintf(str, size, "%u %s", n, unit);
    return(str);
}

void* xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    char msg[64];
    size_t max = sizeof(msg);
    void *p = NULL;

    info("Allocating %s\n", bytes(msg, max, size));
    p = malloc(size);
    memset(p, '1', size);
    return(p);
}


void* xfree(void* p, size_t size)
{
    char msg[64];
    size_t max = sizeof(msg);
    info("Freeing %s\n", bytes(msg, max, size));
    free(p);
    return(NULL);
}
void nap()
{
    const int dur = 10;
    info("Sleeping for %d seconds\n", dur);
    sleep(dur);
}

int main(void)
{
    int err = 0;
    size_t kb = 1024;
    size_t block = 1024 * kb;
    char* p = NULL;

    nap();
    p = xmalloc(block);
    nap();
    p = xfree(p, block);
    nap();
    p = xmalloc(block);
    nap();

    return(err);
}
```

Now, `ps` was run every two seconds from a shell script that helped also print the measurements timestamps. Its output was:

```
# time vsize size rss
1429207116   3940   188   312
1429207118   3940   188   312
1429207120   3940   188   312
1429207122   3940   188   312
1429207124   3940   188   312
1429207126   4968  1216  1364
1429207128   4968  1216  1364
1429207130   4968  1216  1364
1429207132   4968  1216  1364
1429207135   4968  1216  1364
1429207137   3940   188   488
1429207139   3940   188   488
1429207141   3940   188   488
1429207143   3940   188   488
1429207145   5096  1344  1276
1429207147   5096  1344  1276
1429207149   5096  1344  1276
1429207151   5096  1344  1276
1429207153   5096  1344  1276
```

From the values above, and keeping in mind the descriptions given in the man page for `ps(1)`, it seems to me that the best measure is vsize. Is this understanding correct? Note that the man page says that size is a measure of the total amount of dirty pages and rss the amount of pages in physical memory. These could very much become lower than the total memory used by the process.

These experiments were tried on Debian 7.8 running GNU/Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking the total virtual size (`vsize`) of your process is the main measure of process size.  `rss` is just the portion that happens to be using real memory at the moment.  `size` is a measure of how many pages have actually been modified.

A constantly increasing `vsize`, with relatively stable or cyclic `size` and `rss` values might suggest heap fragmentation or a poor heap allocator algorithm.

A constantly increasing `vsize` and `size`, with a relatively stable `rss` might suggest a memory leak, heap fragmentation, or a poor heap allocator algorithm.

You will have to understand something of how a given program uses memory resources in order to use just these external measures of process resource usage to estimate whether it suffers from a memory leak or not.

Part of that involves knowing a little bit about how the heap is managed by the C library `malloc()` and `free()` routines, including what additional memory it might require internally to manage the list of active allocations, how it deals with fragmentation of the heap, and how it might release unused parts of the heap back to the operating system.

For example your test shows that both the total virtual size of the process, and the number of "dirty" pages it required, grew slightly larger the second time the program allocated the same amount of memory again.  This probably shows some of the overhead of `malloc()`, i.e. the amount of memory its own internal data structures required up to that point.  It would have been interesting to see what happened if the program had done another `free()` and `sleep()` before exiting.  It might also be instructive to modify your code so that it calls `sleep()` between calling `malloc()` and `memset()`, and then observe the results from `ps`.

So, a simple program which should only require a fixed amount of memory to  run, or which allocates memory to do a specific unit of work and then should free all of that memory once that unit of work is completed, should show a relatively stable `vsize`, assuming it doesn't ever process more than one unit of work at a time and have a "bad" pattern of allocation that would lead to heap fragmentation.

As you noted, a tool like `valgrind`, along with intimate knowledge of the program's internal implementation, is necessary to show actual memory leaks and prove they are solely the responsibility of the program.

(BTW, you might want to simplify your code somewhat -- don't use unnecessary macros like `info()` in particular, and for this type of example trying to be fancy with printing values in larger units, using extra variables to do size calculations, etc., is also more of an obfuscation than a help.  Too many printfs also obfuscate the code -- use only those you need to see what step the program is at and to see values that are not known at compile time.)